# Generate Random IP address using PHP

Tags: php, numbers

I would like to generate a random IP adress.

Comment: Why'd you accept the more complicated answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check the [mt_rand func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) .

You'll probably want to run this :

```
<?php
    $randIP = mt_rand(0, 255) . "." . mt_rand(0, 255) . "." . mt_rand(0, 255) . "." . mt_rand(0, 255);
?>
```

Answer (score 48):

On **64-bit** PHP:

```
long2ip(rand(0, 4294967295));
```

Working in 2021 in any supported PHP version (7.4 and 8.0).

Note: since almost any machine is x64 nowadays and the development of 32-bit operating systems is being abandoned, if this is not working you may probably want to download the x64 version of PHP.

Comment: To be honest, here is the source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php#61208

Comment: Tested and it's always returning 0.0.0.0

Comment: Of course it returns 0. Problem here is that rand or mt_rand does not support numbers that large. The maximum max-value is something like 2147483647. I explained this in my answere.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ip = long2ip(mt_rand());
```

This way is slightly more readable.

Comment: as i pointed out in my other comment... this wont work for the whole ip range... max ip would be `127.255.255.255` since `mt_rands` max value is 2147483647. If you pass a higher value, it returns `false`.

Answer (score 5):

According to some answeres here, I decided to add **an answere to correct some mistakes** that was made...

```
mt_rand(int $min, int $max);
```

Some samples used this function with a max values of **4294967295**. But this function only supports a max value of **2147483647**, whats actually the half. Passing a higher number will return **false**. Using this function whitout passing anything will also only give the half of the needed value. So

```
long2ip(mt_rand());
```

would return a max ip of `127.255.255.255`

To have the full range you need some like:

```
long2ip(mt_rand()+mt_rand());
```

But even in this sample you will maximum get `255.255.255.254`. So to have a full range you need a third `mt_rand()`.

The correct way to get the total range in a short hand code is:

```
$ip = long2ip(mt_rand()+mt_rand()+mt_rand(0,1));
```

Beware to use + and not *. Because `max value` * `max value` would return `255.255.255.255` as expacted but the chance to get a lower ip isn't that good anymore. To keep good chances using * you could do some like:

```
$ip = long2ip((mt_rand()*mt_rand(1,2))+mt_rand(0,1));
```

Comment: You're answer is wrong. You are talking about an usual 32-bit limitation. Use a 64-bit machine to test @Pavel Strakhov answer.

Comment: So @mgutt , why can my answere be wrong when it does suites to a 32-bit System. Than it must be right. You could comment some like: "this only suites to 32-bit System"

Comment: I would say it's wrong because you say its a general limitation of mt_rand() and other answers must be wrong. I did not downvote, because you can add the 32-bit note on your own. One strange thing is, that the German and French mt_rand() function description has a warning that says that higher max values than 2^32 return mostly even numbers?! http://php.net/manual/de/function.mt-rand.php If this is correct than your version is better for 64-bit systems, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could  also get a pool of valid IPs from your own webserver logs, if you have any:

> cat /var/log/apache2/access_log |cut -d' ' -f1|egrep -v '[a-z]'|sort|uniq >
>   lotsofip.txt

and then in php:

```
$ips = file('lotsofip.txt');    
echo $ips[array_rand($ips)];
```

Answer (score 0):

For IPV6:

```
<?php

function randomizeFromList(array $list)
{
    if (empty($list)) {
        return null;
    }
    $randomIndex = random_int(0, count($list) - 1);

    return $list[$randomIndex];
}

function generateIpv6(): string
{
    $ipv6String = '';
    //IPV6 Pattern ([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}
    $hexSymbols = [
        '0',
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8',
        '9',
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        'd',
        'e',
        'f',
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
        'E',
        'F',
    ];

    $randomLength2 = random_int(1, 7);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $randomLength2; ++$i) {
        $ipv6String    .= randomizeFromList($hexSymbols);
        $randomLength1 = random_int(0, 4);
        for ($j = 0; $j < $randomLength1; ++$j) {
            $ipv6String .= randomizeFromList($hexSymbols);
        }
        $ipv6String .= ':';
    }

    $randomLength3 = random_int(0, 4);
    for ($k = 0; $k < $randomLength3; ++$k) {
        $ipv6String .= randomizeFromList($hexSymbols);
    }

    return $ipv6String;
}

echo(generateIpv6());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ip = intval(rand()%255).'.'.intval(rand()%255).'.'.intval(rand()%255).'.'.intval(rand()%255);
```